# Extracting gene starting location from .fasta gene in python using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, genetics

I have a .fasta file with multiple genes in it. They all have a similar description such as this:

```
>lcl|NZ_LN831034.1_cds_WP_002987659.1_1 [gene=dnaA] [locus_tag=B6D67_RS00005] [db_xref=GeneID:46805773] [protein=chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA] [protein_id=WP_002987659.1] [location=1..1356] [gbkey=CDS]
```

I am trying to extract the gene starting location for all of these genes (ie. "1" from the example above). I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
genes = fasta_file.fasta
records = SeqIO.parse(open(genes), 'fasta')
record = next(records)
parts = record.description.split("..")
print(parts[0])
```

Any help or resources would be appreciated!

Comment: What is error message? It seems `fasta_file.fasta` is variable but should be string.

Comment: ```start = lcl|NZ_LN831034.1_cds_WP_002987659.1_1 [gene=dnaA] [locus_tag=B6D67_RS00005] [db_xref=GeneID:46805773] [protein=chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA] [protein_id=WP_002987659.1] [location=1 ```
is what it returns, and for only the first gene in the list. I want to extract the starting location for all the genes

Comment: I'm afraid your question `(ie. "1" from the example above)` is confusing. As there are many "1" in lcl line, from which part "1" is read?

Comment: Sorry about that! The 1 is read from the start of the gene location. The first number from this part ```[location=1..1356]``` of the original gene description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Hope this help.

```
import re
from Bio import SeqIO

genes = "fasta_file.fasta"
records = SeqIO.parse(genes, 'fasta')

# fasta_file.fasta file has this line only.
>lcl|NZ_LN831034.1_cds_WP_002987659.1_1 [gene=dnaA] [locus_tag=B6D67_RS00005] [db_xref=GeneID:46805773] [protein=chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA] [protein_id=WP_002987659.1] [location=1..1356] [gbkey=CDS]
```

You can get records with `SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta)`. 
To check this,

```
for record in SeqIO.parse(genes, 'fasta'):
    print(record)
```

gives below. And `record.description` has the string info.

> ID: lcl|NZ_LN831034.1_cds_WP_002987659.1_1 Name:
>   lcl|NZ_LN831034.1_cds_WP_002987659.1_1 Description:
>   lcl|NZ_LN831034.1_cds_WP_002987659.1_1 [gene=dnaA]
>   [locus_tag=B6D67_RS00005] [db_xref=GeneID:46805773]
>   [protein=chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA]
>   [protein_id=WP_002987659.1] [location=1..1356] [gbkey=CDS] Number of
>   features: 0 Seq('', SingleLetterAlphabet())

Get number after "location=" with regex.

```
ma = re.search("location=(\d+)\.\.\d+", record.description)
ma.groups()[0] # 1
```